# Can math formulas in LaTeX get rendered properly in an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, github, jekyll, render

At the moment, I am running my blog through [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/), which lets you serve a website through Jekyll. Within my site, I have [MathJax](http://mathjax.org) enabled through the header of my theme, so all of the mathematics that are written in LaTeX are rendered beautifully on my website.

Unfortunately, the one problem I'm having is that I would ideally like the mathematics to be rendered correctly on my RSS feed. However, I don't think I can actually do this through my website.

For other blogs that I subscribe to, their mathematics renders correctly when they make the symbols render as images. These aren't exactly nice, but they do beat having a garbled mess on the text of my RSS feed.

As such, I was wondering if anyone is aware of a way to have the mathematical symbols on my website render using MathJax while simultaneously having my RSS feed pump images into the feed, so those subscribed through RSS can easily read the content on their RSS readers?

Comment: That depends a lot on how much work you're willing to put into it. GitHub's restrictions on Jekyll )when using automatic builds on GitHub pages) will not provide you with any way of doing this. You will (at minimum) have to build the page on your own (or via continuous integration tools).

Comment: Alright thanks @PeterKrautzberger for the reply, so there's no hope then for me if I'd like to stick with GitHub for my site hosting. That's too bad. When I was researching this question online, I saw that you had a few replies to similar questions on StackExchange, namely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055687/conversion-of-mathjax-in-rss-feed-to-images-also-converts-non-latex-strings). I was wondering if that would work? I also found [this](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2012/4/4/math-in-rss-feeds.html) post, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to GitHub Pages.

Comment: The restriction is GitHub's automatic Jekyll build system (not GitHub Page's hosting as such). You can work around this if you add your own build step and push the built page to GitHub; this can be done either locally or using continuous integration services like TravisCI. This way, you can use Jekyll plugins not supported by GitHub's build system or you can post-process your Jekyll output using other tools (e.g., use mathjax-node to process the RSS feed and insert SVG output). That's just a different question.